# Array Allocated in TableView cellforrowat indexpath delegate is leaking memory

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

```
NSMutableArray * lCellColValues = (NSMutableArray * ) nil;
lCellColValues = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

if (0 == lSecModulus) {
    if cObjTransListPtr.count > 0 && lObjTransData.m_cObjSDElemInfoPtr.count > 0) {
        [lCellColValues addObject: lObjTransData.m_cObjTransNamePtr];
        [lCellColValues addObject: [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: lObjTransData.m_cTransCounter] stringValue]];
    } else {
        if (nil != lObjSDElemInfo.m_cObjStartTimePtr) {
            NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
            [dateFormatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT: 0.0]];
            NSString * myDateAsString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: lObjSDElemInfo.m_cObjEndTimePtr];
            [lCellColValues addObject: myDateAsString];
            SAFE_RELEASE(dateFormatter)
        } else {
            [lCellColValues addObject: @""];
        }

    [lCellColValues addObject: [[NSNumber numberWithDouble: lObjSDElemInfo.m_cElementTime] stringValue]];
    }
}

if ((CustSplitCell * ) nil == lObjCellPtr) {
    if (m_cObjTransListPtr.count > 0) {
        lObjCellPtr = [[[CustSplitCell alloc] initWithStyleAndTitles: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: lObjCellIdentifier titles: lCellColValues rowNumber: indexPath.row] autorelease];
    } else {
        [lCellColValues addObject: @""];
        lObjCellPtr = [[[CustSplitCell alloc] initWithStyleAndTitles: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: lObjCellIdentifier titles: lCellColValues rowNumber: indexPath.row] autorelease];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you read the code you have pasted here?

Comment: I am not able to edit the code.Please try to understand @ Praveen S

Comment: If Anybody give the answer they will get good appreciation..

Comment: I have found the solution.I have to release the titles array into which i have collected the array data.this is the called class method.

Comment: this is what I tell you to do: "I think You need to make sure that you use autorelease where appropriate, retain where appropriate, etc." 
If it helped you then you can flag my answer as accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help you: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

I think You need to make sure that you use autorelease where appropriate, retain where appropriate, etc. If you just use alloc/init without autoreleasing, then you need to make sure you have a reference around after you are done with it that you can release it yourself. You take complete ownership of that object when you do things this way. This is all covered in the rules I linked to.

note that this answer is a copy of a comment in this question: [Memory leak for object in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121198/memory-leak-for-object-in-array?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks yu didnt give developer.apple.com as reference.I mean we know that we can access memory management details in website